# Rails has_many :through, how to list all objects to which an object belongs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A character `has_many :conversations, through: :chats`.

However, each conversation belongs to two or more characters: Each `conversation_id` in the chats table is repeated at least twice, each with a different `character_id`, pointing to multiple characters of the same conversation.

**character.rb**

```
has_many :chats, foreign_key: "character_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :conversations, through: :chats, source: :conversation
```

**chat.rb**

```
belongs_to :character
belongs_to :conversation
```

**conversation.rb**

```
has_many :messages
```

Is there a nice quick railsy way to list all the characters that a conversation belongs to? You'd think something like `@conversation.characters` would do the trick, but rails doesn't recognise this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the relationship from your `Conversation` model as well.

```
has_many :chats, dependent: :destroy
has_many :characters, through: :chats
```

Then you can easily call `@conversation.characters`

**Quick tip**

By the way, your `Character` model can be simplified, no need to define the standard `foreign_key` and `source`.

```
has_many :chats, dependent: :destroy
has_many :conversations, through: :chats
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. I'm off to hang myself and improve the gene pool.